# C/C++: What does the comment "/*< */" stand for?

Tags: c++, c, comments, doxygen

I've got a rather general question: I've recently seen many #defines in C/C++ code that were commented with "/*< ... */", for example:

```
#define ARRSIZE(x)          (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))        /*< macro to determine the size of an array */
```

I personally only saw that in comments for defines and a search in Google didn't answer my question either. Does that have any meaning? Is that just common practice or does it come from Doxygen? Or is it any other reason?

Comment: Unrelated: [Use `std::size` instead](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) of the accursed macro. If you don't have c++17 available, look at the third possible implementation. You can grind that out on your own quite easily.

Comment: Check the Doxygen documentation: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc?

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked the [tag:doxygen] tag. That should be made also clear in the question text itself that this is the context.

Comment: Two things: 1. Yes, std::size is an option for this code snippet (but it is an example anyway). I am still used to pure C code :)
2. I've added the doxygen tag because I suspected it might come from the doxygen standards. Imo it is clear from my question text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, `<` is Doxygen's syntax for documentations that come after the item that they document.

An example from the ["Putting documentation after members"](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc) section of the Doxygen documentation:

```
int var; /**< Detailed description after the member */
```

---

What's curious about the example you gave, though, is that it uses a normal comment block (`/*`) as opposed to a documentation block (e.g., `/**`).  I suspect this is an  oversight of the author of this specific example.  Alternatively, it might be that the author extends this convention from documentation blocks to all comments similar in nature.

Comment: That also answers why I couldn't find anything related in Google, because I googled the sketchy version from my code example above. So thank you for your answer, I will document it according to the doxygen documentation in the future.

Comment: @drdolphin Yeah. Or some creative code writer was enjoying to decorate the comment with ASCII art (ignoring that Doxygen users may stumble over this or even not knowing about doc. generators). I admit that I sometimes write comments like `// <-- Here the remarkable thing happened.` into my code. ;-)